# Trouble accessing model properties in controller

Tags: json, ember.js, model, controller

I have a component that takes some current fixture data from my controller like so

```
{{vertical-graph metrics=controller.total_sessions_comparison}}
```

The controller property looks like this

```
total_sessions_comparison: [
    [
        {
            metricNumber: "26%",
            metricText: "September",
            metricStyle: "height: 26%"
        },
        {
            metricNumber: "22%",
            metricText: "October",
            metricStyle: "height: 22%"
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            metricNumber: "74%",
            metricText: "September",
            metricStyle: "height: 74%"
        },
        {
            metricNumber: "78%",
            metricText: "October",
            metricStyle: "height: 78%"
        }
    ]
],
```

My model hook in my router is loading data from a custom express api like this

```
return Ember.$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api');
```

Currently my API is returning JSON that looks like this

```
{
"total_sessions": 288,
"current_month": "May",
"current_month_year": "2015",
"last_month": "December",
"last_month_year": "2014"
}
```

I can access the model data in the template just fine (these are all under index) but I'm having some problems understanding how to take the month names for instance in the controller property and instead of hard coding them use the ones being dynamically passed through the API. The model property looks like `current_month` and `last_month` which like I said work in the template but I can't get them to work in the controller.

Or is there maybe a better way of doing this than I currently am that would make this easier?

Comment: your question doesn't make much sense to me. you just randomly started talking about months but the controller property is about metrics and I don't see `current_month` or `last_month` anywhere. Show me your route code

Comment: Updated it with the current response from my JSON API, also the route code is the Ember.$.getJSON(...) bit, it's in the model hook of the index route.

Comment: thats a start. Now what do you mean by "get them to work in the controller"

Comment: So in the controller property there I have the months as strings, but I want to use the ones being passed from the JSON API instead of writing them out. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so by default, what is returned from the `model` hook in your route is set as the `model` property on the corresponding controller. This is done via the built in `setupController(controller, model)` hook. If you want to set more properties on your controller or need some more fine grained control, feel free to override setupController. For example, your json is parsed into an object that is set as the model when the promise resolves. To have a `current_month` variable on the controller set to this value, you could:

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('current_month', model.current_month);
}
```

You no longer have a model being set, unless you `this._super(controller, model)` inside of the overridden `setupController` if you need this.

Comment: So I added your code for `last_month` and added an empty property to the controller, but I still can't call the property from inside the controller. How do I call it?

Comment: call it? if you are trying to access the property, use `this.get('last_month')`. And doing so can only be done inside of a function.

Comment: Yeah in the console I see this error when I try to do that `Error while processing route: index this.get is not a function TypeError: this.get is not a function`

Comment: this.get() should be happening in the controller not the route. please show the failing controller code

Comment: `total_sessions_comparison: [
  [
   {
    metricNumber: "26%",
    metricText: this.get('last_month'),
    metricStyle: "height: 26%"
   },
   {
    metricNumber: "22%",
    metricText: "October",
    metricStyle: "height: 22%"
   },
  ],
  [
   {
    metricNumber: "74%",
    metricText: "September",
    metricStyle: "height: 74%"
   },
   {
    metricNumber: "78%",
    metricText: "October",
    metricStyle: "height: 78%"
   }
  ]
 ],`

Comment: yeah I told you already, you can only do so from within a function so this is obviously not going to work. try `total_sessions_comparison: function(){return [ [ { metricNumber: "26%", metricText: this.get('last_month'), metricStyle: "height: 26%" }, { metricNumber: "22%", metricText: "October", metricStyle: "height: 22%" }, ], [ { metricNumber: "74%", metricText: "September", metricStyle: "height: 74%" }, { metricNumber: "78%", metricText: "October", metricStyle: "height: 78%" } ] ];}.property('last_month')`

Comment: Got it, didn't see anything about a function. Thanks.